# jQuery JSON parse - object elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, parsing

This is my JSON: (This is AJAX response data)

```
{"id":"1","code":"43","doc":"{\"date\":\"2016\",\"name\":\"NAME1\",\"id\":\"7\"}"}
```

I would like to parse this JSON with jQuery:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

This is doc: `console.log(obj.doc);`

```
{\"date\":\"2016\",\"name\":\"NAME1\",\"id\":\"7\"}
```

But how do I refer to the "name"? 
I do not refer to obj.doc.name, because the "name" is not element on the object.

Comment: You can clearly see that the the value of `obj.doc` is a string containing JSON. You'd need to apply `JSON.parse(obj.doc)` again. Better however would be to fix the code that generates the JSON to not double encode your data.

Comment: It appears as though `doc` is itself JSON, so you'll need to parse it. Something like `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); obj.doc = jQuery.parseJSON(obj.doc);`

Comment: THX! This is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value of the "doc" attribute in your object is a string, you will need to parse that value to treat it as a JSON object.

After the first parse you could do:

```
var doc = JSON.parse(obj.doc)
```

Then you can access `doc.name`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case response is already JSON. You want parse `data.doc` only.

You can do this like that:

```
data.doc = jQuery.parseJSON(data.doc)
```

and now when you get what you wanted.

```
> console.log(data.doc.name)
NAME1
```